# zsh globbing - Find files with duplicate filename strings

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

I have a directory of files with filenames of the form `<num1>v<num2>.txt`.  I'd like to find all files for which `<num1>` is a duplicate.  When duplicates are found, we should delete the ones with smaller `<num2>`.

Is this possible?  I could easily write a python script to handle this, but thought it might be a nice application of built-in zsh features.

**Example**

In the following list of files, the first three have duplicate `<num1>` parts.  As well, the fourth and fifth are duplicate.

```
012345v1.txt
012345v2.txt
012345v3.txt
3333v4.txt
3333v7.txt
11111v11.txt
```

I would like to end up with directory containing

```
012345v3.txt
3333v7.txt
11111v11.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
files=(<->v<->.txt(n))
typeset -A h
for f ($files) h[${f%%v*}]=$f
keep=($h)
echo rm ${files:|keep}
```

(remove `echo` if happy)

- `<->`: any sequence of digits (`<x-y>` glob operator with no bound specified)
- `(n)`: numeric sort
- `${f%%v*}`: standard/ksh greedy pattern stripping from the end.
- `${files:|keep}`: array subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar too much with `zsh` shell, and I'm coming with below `awk` command combination with `find` and `sort` which make sorting the files found first with `natural sort of (version) numbers within text` from [`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) says.

Then passing `awk` with defining `-F'v'` and add to an array based on first duplicated part of file name (this ensure that last one is keeping in array), so the command I'm talking would be as follows to result the *files with big v number*:

```
awk -F'v' '{U[$1]=$1"v"$2}END{for(x in U)print U[x]}' <(find . -type f|sort -V)
./012345v3.txt
./3333v7.txt
./11111v11.txt
```

Now you got the list of files which you should keep and delete rest.